# When using onValue to listen to a Firebase realtime database for updates, is it possible to retrieve the event type of child_added or child_changed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following to query a Firebase realtime database for updates in a React application:

```
onValue(query(ref(db, 'users')), (snapshot) => {

  if(snapshot.exists()) {
   // do stuff with snapshot.val()
  }

}, (cancelCallback) => {
  console.log(cancelCallback);
});
```

As expected, this returns all the data that exists under the `users` node when instantiated and will execute again every time data at this node is changed, added or removed.

Is it possible to retrieve the event type of `child_added`, `child_changed` or `child_removed` from the snapshot?

I have checked the documentation at Firebase and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the event type of child_added,
> child_changed or child_removed from the snapshot?

It's not possible with `onValue()` but you can use [`onChildAdded()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#onchildadded), [`onChildChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#onchildchanged) and [`onChildRemoved()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#onchildremoved) respectively.

Comment: Thank you for that response, however, if we are dealing with 100s of thousands of users, it does not seem practical to have more than one listener if we can setup the one `onValue` to listen to all changes. I suppose i can parse the response in-order to determine the change that triggered the listener, but with respect to scale, wouldn't you agree that having to setup multiple listeners does not seem practical?

Comment: You could have three listeners that call a unique function. Then what can be considered as redundancy is minimal. The number of users doesn't have any impact since listeners are set in the front end.